# Is there a type-safe way to reduce() a larger object into a new type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, reduce

I have a data structure that represents the results from a database query, which is an object with many properties, all scalars (in my case, all either strings or numbers).  I want to extract a portion of these properties and fill out a new object that has a defined shape.

```js
const input: Record<string, string | number> = { name: 'Jane', age: 42, fav_pet: 'Dog', fav_col: 'Blue', fav_dest: 'Paris' };
const FAVS = ['pet', 'col', 'dest'] as const;
type FavsType = {
  pet: string;
  col: string;
  dest: string;
}

const output: FavsType = FAVS.reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: input['fav' + key] }), {});
//    ~~~~~~
//    ^^^^^^ Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'FavsType': pet, col, dest
```

The problem is, if I use the `reduce` method to do this, Typescript is unable to figure out that the return value of the reduce must contain an object in the correct shape.  I've also tried using `Object.fromEntries(FAVS.map())` with similar results.

Is there any type-safe solution to this which doesn't involve assigning each property explicitly?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=2&ssc=36&pln=2&pc=45#)

Comment: The return type of reduce is inferred from the second argument (in this case `{}`) or provided by the [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) (e.g. `.reduce<FavsType>(...)`).

Comment: You could use a type assertion `const output: FavsType = FAVS.reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: input['fav' + key] }), <FavsType>{});`

Comment: Also you could make the `const FAVS` type safe by using the keyof operations, since the array only conatins values wich are keys of `FavsType` `const FAVS: (keyof FavsType)[] = ['pet', 'col', 'dest']`

Comment: @IAMTHEBEST that actually produces a weaker type than `as const` because it allows for mutation.

Comment: @IAMTHEBEST I view the relation the other way - it's `FavsType` that contains all the entries from `FAVS`. So, to me it seems more logical to derive in the other direction as a mapped type: `type FavsType = { [key in typeof FAVS[number]]: string; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be Typescript. When Typescript encounter the reduce, it have to declare new variables that it have to type.

```
const output: FavsType = FAVS.reduce((acc, key) => ({
  ...acc,

  [key]: input[`fav${key}`],
}), ------> {} <------);
```

The accumulator being initialized as `{}` then typescript infer the type `'{}'`.

Mutating the accumulator won't change it's type from typescript point of view.

You will have to tell typescript

> Trust me, the returned type is of FavsType

That's where assertions comes in :

```
const output: FavsType = FAVS.reduce((acc, key) => ({
  ...acc,

  [key]: input[`fav${key}`],
}), {}) as FavsType;
```

Ideally typescript should see the mutation of the object and infer the proper reduce returned type, but it ain't that "smart" yet.

Comment: In the future Typescript might be smart enough to determine it by itself, but for now just use `const output: FavsType = FAVS.reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: input['fav' + key] }), <FavsType>{});`

Comment: The difference between your proposal and mine, it that you tell typescript that the accumulator worth FavsType at the accumulator creation, which is wrong. Casting the returned value of the reduce in other hand is "correct", the returned value do match the FavsType. Both works but I think that it's important to maintain some kind of coherence

Comment: I see what you mean, mine answer initializes the accumulater `{}` and I tell Typescript the type is FavsType. The compiler is then smartenough to determine the type based on the return type of the reduce, since it returns the accumulator. With your answer you first do the operation and at the end you tell Typescript the type is correct.

Comment: I would use the method suggested by @IAMTHEBEST if it meant that adding incompatible props in the reduce would get caught, but it doesn't.  TS is satisfied regardless, which makes me more inclined to get the object into the shape I know is correct and then stamp it as such, as suggested by Grégory.  It's a real shame that TS can't do this.

Comment: lol at "Be typescript".  So there's no better way to do this?

Comment: @Andrew that's the way I'm thinking all the time, trying to think like the compiler/interpretor. There is unfortunately no help implemented directly into Typescript. Can you imagine if typescript told you itself than it can't infer the type change ? would be great.

Comment: Haskel is smarter, it is able to infer the type in most cases. So won't need to specify any generic type parameter. So have I been told, I never used Haskel. But it is simular to F#